# How to Set a Selector Variable with Quotes and Double Quotes in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

**How must I set this selector variable to work in CasperJS (works in Chrome console)?**

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-product-unique-key="4_0_1"] [pf-aria-text="widgets.efgenericproduct.paymentaccount.Movements"]')[0]
```

Here is the test result:

```
FAIL Find an element matching: ('[data-product-unique-key="4_0_1"] [pf-aria-text="widgets.efgenericproduct.paymentaccount.Movements"]')[0] 
#    type: assertExists 
#    file: /home//dev/casperjs/ccm/scenarios/global.js 
#    subject: false 
#    selector: "('[data-product-unique-key=\"4_0_1\"] [pf-aria-text=\"widgets.efgenericproduct.paymentaccount.Movements\"]')[0]"
```

Here is my current code:

```
// I escape the doublequotes using backslash
var btnMovements = "('[data-product-unique-key=\"4_0_1\"] [pf-aria-text=\"widgets.efgenericproduct.paymentaccount.Movements\"]')[0]"
casper.csvexport = function() {
    casper.thenOpen('https://www.foobank.com/ap/ba/fp/html/e-finance/assets', function() {
        });
    casper.waitForSelector(
        btnMovements,
        function success() {
            this.test.assertExists(btnMovements);
            this.click(btnMovements);
        },
        function fail() {
            this.test.assertExists(btnMovements);
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your selector is incorrect:**

```
var btnMovements = "('[data-product-unique-key=\"4_0_1\"] [pf-aria-text=\"widgets.efgenericproduct.paymentaccount.Movements\"]')[0]"
```

**The correct selector should be:**

```
var btnMovements = '[data-product-unique-key="4_0_1"] [pf-aria-text="widgets.efgenericproduct.paymentaccount.Movements"]';
```